# when CCH channel encounter with congestion?

Tags: veins

I am using OMNeT++ 5.4.1, Veins 4.7.1, and SUMO 0.30.0. I sould solve congestion.
How can I understand capacity of CCH channel is more than 0.65% ?
Or how can I understand when I should control congestion?
I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In Veins 5.0, the 802.11p MAC layer class (`Mac1609_4`) emits a signal `Mac1609_4::sigChannelBusy` (see [Mac1609_4.h line 72](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.h#L72)) whenever it senses that the channel turns from idle to busy or vice versa (appending a bool parameter to the signal to indicate which is which - see [Mac1609_4.cc line 880](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L880)). Your application can rely on this signal to determine when the channel is busy for more than, say, 65% during a given sampling interval.

Similar functionality exists in Veins 4.7.1 (see [its Mac1609_4.cc line 952](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L952)).

Comment: Thanks Mr sommer but when CCH is busy it does not mean it has congestion in veins

Comment: Can you please give an example of how it is used?